# Why JetBrains IDEA generate constructor always has separate line for the first parameter?

Tags: intellij-idea, constructor, jetbrains-ide

When I use the JetBrains IDEA generate the constructor for Java Class, I always get a separate line for the first parameter. For example:

```
public Test(//this parameter in next line.
        Class<Test> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
}
```

I think this should be some configure for the template, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Check your code style settings, it's not a default behavior.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes I know, But I don't want to reset to default. Because I change a lot of things...and not sure why this issue occur. I think it should be the template issue, but I have reviewed all Java related templates and not found any problem.

Comment: [Check here](http://i.imgur.com/Bg9YnXU.png).